# Getting the graph structure with Networkx

Tags: python, networkx

I'm using Networkx to build a dependency graph.
For example I have this struct.

```
A
 +-B
   +-C
 +-H

AA
 +-BB
   +-CC
```

which I build easily with Networkx like that

```
G = nx.DiGraph()

G.add_edge(A,B)
G.add_edge(A,H)
G.add_edge(B,C)

G.add_edge(AA,BB)
G.add_edge(BB,)
```

(By the way I didn't know how I could set a root node so i have a root = set() where I have all my roots, in this case root=(A))

My question is how can I get the all hierarchy by specifying a node ? For example if I would do like:

```
 G.successors[A]
```

It will give me

```
{A: {B: {C: {} }, H: {} }
```

But at the moment if I Do

```
G.successors[A]
```

It only gives me

```
{H:{} , B:{} }
```

Which is correct but where is the rest??? Also If a Do G.successors[B] it returns me

```
{C:{}}
```

Which is correct but why don't he put it in when I do G.successors[A] ?

And an other question. Is it possible with Networksx to get the "Path" from a node to another ?
For example?

```
[A,H] or [A,B,C]
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://networkx.lanl.gov/reference/algorithms.traversal.html

```
print nx.dfs_successors(G,'A')

>> {A: [H,B], B:[C]}
```

I don't how to generate the structure you gave in example though..